# Cumulants of square of Poisson distribution

Tags: information-theory, poisson-distribution, perturbation-theory, poisson-process, cumulants

I'm writing up a derivation of an expression for mutual information between weakly interacting Poisson processes.  I'm running into an expression that looks like this:

$$\log\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\epsilon X + (\epsilon X)^2 + \log\left(1+\epsilon X + (\epsilon X)^2\right)}\right]$$

for a Poisson variable $X$ and a small parameter $\epsilon>0$.  I want to expand this out to $O(\epsilon^2)$ and throw away higher-order terms, but I need to know that those terms are finite.  If the $X^2$ term weren't there, I could expand the expression in terms of cumulants, but I'm not sure whether the moment-generating function for $X^2$ exists.

Is this expression finite, and if so, how can I demonstrate that?